# Convert string to UTF-8 - Google API Geocode - Android

Tags: android, utf-8

I am using http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode to get and address from some coordinates.

The thing is that my APP is encoded in UTF-8 and as it appears the response from the API is not. So I am getting a couple of strange characters where there should be accentuation.

So I need to find a way to convert the string to UTF-8.

Bellow is the snippet of the code where I get the String.

```
JSONObject addressComponents1 = addressComponentsArray.getJSONObject(1);
rua = addressComponents1.getString("long_name");
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(rua);
Log.i("Rua", rua);
```

Comment: I would tend to say that it comes from the reading of the result. post the code where you read the data from the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use URLEncoder to do so

```
String value = "My String"; 
String encValue = URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
```

http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer moh.sukhni but it didn´t work.

The output got worse. From Rua Henrique BadraA³ to Rua+Henrique+Badar%C3%83%C2%B3

Comment: The answer is totally right %C3%83%C2%B3 is the encoded result of A³ character.

Comment: Sorry @moh.sukhni ... I need to display the Character with the proper accentuation.

Comment: but that is not what the question was

Comment: @moh.sukhni I marked you answer as the right one because you did answer my question.

But I wasn't able to get the correct accentuation when I decoded. It went back to the A³,

If you are able to answer me I will appreciate, if not I will try to formulate a better question.

Comment: Here is the answer for the problem I was having.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376373/getting-the-right-accentuation-from-google-api-geocode-android